# How to get Noun Chunks using Stanza

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, spacy, stanza

I previously used `Spacy` for language parsing. Spacy has inbuild functionality to get `noun_chunks`.

As spacy does not have language models for `Arabic`. I am trying to use **`stanza`** for this purpose.

I am able to extract entities and tokens from it but unable to extract Noun Chunks using stanza.

I dont want to use **CoreNLP server** for that.

Can anyone help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: `noun_chunks` are not implemented for all languages in spaCy. Arabic does not have a `noun_chunks` syntax iterator at this point (v3.0.3).

Comment: ok. Is there any way programmatically I can extract it?

Comment: You can write a `noun_chunks` iterator that works for the Arabic UD dependency trees. Look at the `spacy/lang/*/syntax_iterators.py` for languages other than English or German in spacy to see examples for noun chunks from UD trees.